# Find value based on id on separate sheets in excel

Tags: excel

I have one sheets with only ids (year)

```
                           | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |
Vendor | Name | Product ID | ?   |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |
1      | Test | 20         | ?   |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |
1      | Test2| 30         | ?   |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |
2      | Test3| 50         | ?   |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |
```

and multiple sheets (months) with ids and values

Here is my jan sheet

```
Vendor | Name | Product ID | Value | Month
1      | Test | 20         | 5     | January
1      | Test2| 30         | 7     | January
2      | Test3| 50         | 9     | January
```

Aand another sheet (feb) like this:

```
Vendor | Name | Product ID | Value | Month
2      | Test3| 50         | 8     | February
```

How can I import/lookup the values into a single sheet (year) ?

Here is what I have tried:

`= VLOOKUP(C2;jan!C:C;4;FALSE)`

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Yes it is possible. Your issue (not mentioned by you) might be that the search array you are using is a single column (`C:C`) and you are attempting to return a value from its "fourth" column. In addition it looks (you have not mentioned what is where, so I'm guessing again) as though C2 might contain the `Product ID` label rather than a value to be looked up.

So I would suggest:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C3;INDIRECT(D$1&"!C:D");2;FALSE);"")
```

The outside is just error handling so that blanks display where values are not found (as would seem to be if searching for `20` in February).

The search term (`C3`) is anchored to facilitate copying across for the different months (for each month the ID is still from the same columns). The row number I have increased by one as there seems no point in looking up the label.

I suggest INDIRECT so that the headings on the (year) sheet can be incorporated into the formula and save an alternative selection sheet by sheet. ColumnsC:D (and hence `2`) chosen based on what you show above rather than what your formula suggests may be reality.

Applied to what I think might be D3, you should be able to copy the formula across and down to suit.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the extensive explanation! This works great!